# Все запросы к sqlite падают ошибкой блокировки

Tags: php, windows, sqlite, pdo, docker

### Проблема:

Есть приложение на php которое использует хранилице sqlite, посредством pdo. Я поднял docker c окружением Ubuntu+php+sqlite3+php-sqlite3 (тоесть у меня чистая установка, и все установленно из пакетов). Запускаю приложение и наблюдаю через пару секунд `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 5 database is locked`.

### Шаги воспроизведения:

```
php -a
php > $db = net PDO('sqlite:./test.db');
php > $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
php > try{$db->query("CREATE TABLE test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)");}catch(Exception $e){print $e->getMessage();}
####SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 5 database is locked
```

### Что нужно:

Я уже понял что с этой бедой несовладаю, но хотел бы понять почему sqlite с дефолтными настройками на чистой убунте не хочет работать.

### Обновление:

Методом тыка выяснил что если файл базы положить в директорию на которую ссылаеться windows (тоесть docker run -v C:\win-dir:/var/www) то sqlite все время выдает ошибку блока. Со стороны убунты файл имет достаточно прав для редактирования и сам php запускаеться от root. 
Возможная причина это файловая система CIFS,которая используеться docker для подключения windows папки к ubuntu. В одном источнике нашел что sqlite совместо c cifs/nfs должен использовать параметр nolock в параметрах подключиния (тоесть в mount). Так как я не могу это исправить то я не могу подвердить что в этом проблема.

Comment: Это же sqlite. Такую ошибку он выдает если открыт коннект к базе и не закрыт коннект и идет попытка открыть еще один коннект пусть даже в рамках одного процесса.

Comment: @vitidev я понимаю что в sqlite блокировки не построчные, но в моем примере я показал что выполняеться всего один конект и один запрос, и сразу блокировка. Никакой конкуреции нету.

Comment: Вы де-факто обращаетесь к внешней файловой системе и так или иначе будете играть по ее правилам вне зависимости от разрешений внутри контейнера. Глубже копать не берусь, но вы и сами видите, что блокировка снимается не мгновенно.